# Combining 2 linq queries - group and join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 separate tables in my Db for Customers and their related Ethnicity. The customers table holds foreign key Id for the ethnicity. I would like to create a Linq query that shows the total of each ethnicity for reporting purposes. For example something like...

```
 +------------+------------------+
 |  Ethnicity | Customer Count   |
 +------------+------------------+
 |  White     |   100            |
 +------------+------------------+
 |  Black     |   50             |
 +------------+------------------+
 |  Chinese   |   20             |
 +------------+------------------+ etc...
```

So far I have the following two LINQ queries:

```
var customers = repository.GetAll<Customer>();
var ethnicities = repository.GetAll<Ethnicity>();

var query1 = customers.GroupBy(c => c.EthnicityId).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

query 1 shows totals but with ethnicity ID instead of text (EthnicityType).

```
var query2 = from c in customers
             join e in ethnicities on c.EthnicityId equals e.Id
             where (c.EthnicityId == e.Id)
             select new { Ethnicity = e.EthnicityType, Count = ??? };
```

query 2 joins the two tables but how to group this so that I get the Total instead of individual records? Hope this makes sense, would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query2 = query1.Join(ethnicities, x => x.Key, 
                                      y => EthnicityId, 
                                   (x, y) => new { Ethnicity = y.EthnicityType, 
                                                      Count = x.Count });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do what you want but if the number of ethnicities is small you can simply create a lookup table on the client side and use it to map ID's to descriptive names:

```
var customers = repository.GetAll<Customer>();
var ethnicities = repository.GetAll<Ethnicity>().ToDictionary(e => e.Id);

var query1 = customers
  .GroupBy(c => c.EthnicityId)
  .Select(g => new { Key = ethnicities[g.Key], Count = g.Count() };
```

`ToDictionary(e => e.Id)` is used to create a dictionary mapping ID's to names and the dictionary is then used to look up the name using `ethnicities[g.Key]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
var query2 = 
    from e in ethnicities
    join c in customers on e.Id equals c.EnthnicityId
    into g
    where g.Any()
    select new { Ethnicity = g.First(), Count = g.Count() };
```